# Finding Perfect Numbers in C - Compile Error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, double

I'm writing a simple program that finds the perfect numbers up to a given range. Here's what I have:

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<strings.h>    
#include<unistd.h>


void Compute(double range);

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
  double range = 40000000;

  printf("range: %f\n", range);

  Compute(range);
}

void Compute(double range)
{
  double numbers[range];

  double total = 0;
  double sum = 0;
  double num;
  double j;

  for(num = 1; num < range; num++){
    sum = 0;

    for(j = 1; j < num; j++){
      if((num % j) == 0){
        sum+=j;
      }
    }

    if(sum == num){
      numbers[total] = sum;
      total++;
    }

  } 

  printf("Total: %f\n", total);

  for(j = 0; j < total; j++){
    printf("%f \n", numbers[j]);
  }

}
```

However, when I try to compile the program, I keep getting `error: expression must have integral type` error for almost all the operations in the `Compute()` method. It works fine for integer data types, but not for `double`. I'm using Intel C Compiler. Any ideas why the compiler is complaining?

Comment: I take it this is a trimmed down version of a longer code? Otherwise you are including a bunch of headers that you don't need.

Comment: On another note, that's a rather inefficient way to check whether a number is perfect. Disregarding number theoretic knowledge that makes the check nearly instantaneous, you can stop the division at the square root, since if `n = a*b` with `a != b`, the smaller of `a` and `b` is less than the square root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot create an array with a floating point size

```
double numbers[range];
```

the argument must be an integer. Imagine if `range` was 2.5 -  C won't allow an array of 2.5 doubles. An array must have an integer number of elements

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you know what `double` means.

For example: what exactly would you expect `double numbers[1.23];` to do? *(rhetorical question)*

The `%` operator also requires integer operands (you can use `fmod()` to get a fractional modulus, but I doubt that's what you want).

Comment: That's not a correct answer. You shouldn't post questions as answers - instead you should ask this in a comment. (I know, you can't comment, atm.)

Comment: I wrote my answer in the form of a question because the original question was in the form of an answer: `expression must have integral type` is precisely why the compiler complains.

Answer (score 1):

Your array:

```
double numbers[range];
```

needs in integral size for the array.   Use a cast such as.

```
double numbers[(int)range];
```

Same with your other uses of double variables.